# deploy a ASP.NET Core 2.0 webApp to Linux Server

Tags: linux, web, hosting, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a ASP.NET Core 2.0 web App. I want to deploy this to Linux server. Please let me know the options and steps to do it. If Linux has Apache server running on it, can I host it there